# NSDictionary writeToFile

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

Is there a size limit to saving dictionaries?

I am attempting to write a rather large dictionary with around 100 keys with nested dictionaries using writeToFile: but it never writes and is always false.

Is this a limitation or am I doing something incorrect,

The code i use is the following.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist"];   

[myDict writeToFile: fullPath  atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Are you sure you dont have any non-codable objects embedded in the dictionary tree.
Theres a limited set of objects that conform to NSCoding. Have a check in the console I have a feeling it barfs the offending object detail into there if that is the case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no size limit (save for memory and disk space).

What are the contents of `myDict`?

If it is anything but the small set of classes allowed in property lists, then you can't use `writeToFile:atomically:`.

Either you would need to limit your dictionary to only containing instances of those classes *or* you will need to use a different archiving method.

In particular, a lot of the JSON libraries will spew `NSNULL` instances into the collections.  Those can't be archived.  You need to either edit them out or replace them with objects that *can* be archived.

Of relevance:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i

Comment: i had the same issue and the problem was [NSNull null] object in the dictionary :)

Answer (score 27):

There is one more trick to this, besides using only eligible objects (instances of NSNumber, NSString, NSData etc)   the keys have to be NSString objects.  Normally you can use any object for NSDictionary key but to have a successful writeToFile: the keys in the NSDictionary need to be instances NSString.

Comment: I was having trouble saving an NSDictionary using writeToFile, this answer helped me solve the problem I was having. Quirks like this can be such a silly waste of time to troubleshoot.

Comment: Wanted to confirm that this indeed did solve my problem! I was using NSNumber(s) as key but the dictionary won't write, after converting the numbers to strings it worked! Thanks, @Otuken!

Answer (score 5):

I would add one more trick as well that I ran into on Lion. The folder that you want to write the plist to must exist before you call NSDictionary's `writeToFile:atomically:`. You can use NSFileManager to test existence and create a new folder if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I had this, as is mentioned by others the dictionary can not be saved with some data types (notable NULLs).

Because my dictionary was from a server (in form of JSON) I could not guarantee what was in it so I saved the RAW data (from the dataWithContentsOfURL) before serialization of the JSON.  To this end I am guessing you could convert the dict to NSData and save that - something like;

```
NSData *convetedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:JSONDict];
```

And then later retrieve and convert back like this.

```
NSDictionary *JSONDict = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:convertedDATA];
```