# writeToFile:atomically: does not work on iOS 6.1.3?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a plist (`NSDictionary`) which I intended can be changed by user data input. Here is what I have done.

```
NSString *path = (the path for the plist)
NSMutableDictionary *plistFile = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentOfFile:path] mutableCopy];
[plistFile setObject:(an NSString object) forKey:(an NSString key)];
[plistFile writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

So this is what I have coded. It works well on `iPad 3 (new iPad) (iOS 6.1.2)` and my `XCode (4.6) simulator (iOS 6)`. However, it does not work on my `iPad mini (iOS 6.1.3)`. I have found the problem which is in the last step. When I wrote

```
BOOL success = [plistFile writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"%@",@(success));
```

The console always prints 0 which means it does not succeed. But on my iPad 3 and simulator it prints 1, which means success.

That is all I can describe because there is no exception being thrown out or other output. By the way, my iPad 3 (on which it works) is jailbroken but the iPad mini is not. Nevertheless, I use my developer account to codesign on both devices. Can anyone help me? Or else can anyone point to me a new solution?

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460016/nsdictionary-writetofile

Comment: This related question looks relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005544/writetofile-working-in-sim-but-not-on-device

Comment: If it works on jail-broken device, but not non-jailbroken device, I wonder to what path you're writing the file. Is it the `Documents` folder? It cannot be the bundle or anywhere outside the app's sandbox.

Comment: The serialize procedure it doesn't support all the kind of objects out of the box. Are you sure that you are serializing on disk just NSArray, NSString, NSNumber, NSData, NSDictionary or their mutable versions? an in which path are you writing, it looks like a permission problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use

```
NSError * error = nil;
BOOL success = [plistFile writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
NSLog(@"Success = %d, error = %@", success, error);
```

And then check what error occures. Maybe it can helps you.
And you can write only to the document directory. You may have some troubles with your path.

Comment: Yes, I have found the problem. I wrote directly to the resource path. But is it allowable on jailbroken devices? I can see the file that I just wrote in the program through iFile.

Comment: @zyl1024 It works on jailbroken devices and simulator, but not non-jailbroken devices. Don't write to the bundle. Write to the `Documents` folder.

Comment: @Rob Thank you. I have been confused by this for several days.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see from your code if you have done this, but your `path` needs to be the sandboxed app directory.

```
NSArray* pathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* path = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [pathList objectAtIndex:0]];
```